# Find Total salary using distinct and sum?

Tags: mysql

How to get the sum of distinct IDs and their respective salaries?

```
ID   Salary
1    1000
2    2000
1    1000
2    2000
```

In above I want to get the out like this

```
Total salary 
3000
```

I tried and made the output like this

```
ID   Salary
1    1000
2    2000
```

---

```
select distinct(id), sum (salary) from employee group by id
```

Main issue is that I am not able to total after applying distinct to the ID.

Want to remove the duplicate entries of id and sum of there distinct ID?

Comment: At first, why there are duplicate entries ?

Comment: Actually it is an assignment question to crack..

Comment: Your table has no PRIMARY KEY. The assignment therefore cannot relate to MySQL. It makes no sense.

Comment: Check answer now you query solved

Answer (score 1):

Check this Query is,

#### Query

```
SELECT SUM (
    DISTINCT salary
    ) FROM employee
```

#### Result

```
SUM(DISTINCT SALARY)
--------------------
3000
```

#### Check <kbd>**[Demo SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c476e/35/0)**</kbd>

---

You can do also by this way,

```
SELECT SUM(salary) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, salary 
   FROM employee 
   GROUP BY id,salary
) AS emp
```

Check this <kbd>**[Demo SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c476e/40/0)**</kbd>

Comment: No my friend, If Employee C has 2000 salary then?

Comment: So what try your self.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be, remove duplicate records and write simple query. Second way is this query, in which I have taken `MAX(Highest)` salary for each employee in sub query, and then applied `SUM()` from calculating total salary.

```
    SELECT SUM (sal) from
   (
        SELECT MAX (salary)  as sal
        FROM employee GROUP BY id
    ) as tbl
```

Comment: This would be more useful if it explained how it works and why it is an answer to the question. As the question is for an assignment (explained in a comment posted after this answer) it may be better to give an explanation that educates the asker rather than providing code they may be able to copy without understanding.

Comment: Hey now you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
select sum(salary) from( select distinct id, salary from 
employee) as t
```

Comment: No need to use distinct along with group by and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 100% work

```
SELECT SUM(salary) as "Total salary" 
        FROM(SELECT DISTINCT id, salary FROM 
           employee GROUP BY id,salary ) as e
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
It will work definitely
It will sum of salary with same id only.

```
Select SUM(salary) as total from employee group by id;
```